# How to give discount from Shipping price in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I have created a Shopping cart price rule with Coupon 'EL10' and now I want that if a customer apply this coupon code then amount should discounted from Shipping Method price only, not from Subtotal or Grand Total.

I googled it but didn't found any solution for this.

Can anyone help me in this ?